# Consumption Plan Monitoring

Tags: azure-functions

I have a two functions each deployed in to two different Function Apps, both of these App are utilising a consumption plan.. from the portal this is listed simply as NorthEuropePlan, and selecting that explicitly shows me that there are two Function Apps connected.

Q1: Does this mean that they are actually using the same genuine plan (as would be the case w/ App Svc Plan), or does it simply mean that they are both "sharing" resources in north europe region's pool?

Q2: I split these functions apart to see which was using most resources, connections etc, but i can't work out how to see how many consumption instances are actually being scaled-out, and how heavy they are being loaded.. where do i find this info?

I.e. i can't see any "consumption node" entries in metrics at all... App Insights is configured, and i can see a node count on the Live Metrics... but don't really know how this correlates as both Function Apps are configures with the same App Insights

Comment: You should be able to see this in Application Insights if you have it connected

Comment: Re: scaling, what triggers are you using? Functions uses different scaling algorithms for different triggers (ex. queue length means nothing to an HTTP trigger) and some are more aggressive than others.

Comment: Event Hub @KatyShimizu 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: Yes, your function apps are using the same consumption app service plan, which means both will scale together, always sharing the same VM resources. However, the apps run in separate Job Objects and don't share the same memory space (working set).

Q2: This information would be in Application Insights. Check out the [View telemetry in App Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#view-telemetry-in-app-insights) section of the Functions monitoring documentation for information on the various tabs (one of which, Servers, shows instances.) I don't believe it's possible to view threads in App Insights, but you can view executions. Not sure what you mean by connections.

You may also want to take a look at the following documentation and posts, which cover Functions and Event Hubs in high-throughput scenarios:

- [Azure Functions scalability best practices documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#scalability-best-practices)
- [Processing 100,000 Events Per Second on Azure Functions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/09/19/processing-100000-events-per-second-on-azure-functions/)

Comment: by connections, i am referring to the metric labelled "connections" in the a function app, when you click on the metric button.. :)

i still don't quite understand how, if i have multiple function apps, all using consumption plan, i can see how each one is scaling... i guess i would need to attach them to different Application Insights instances?

Also can't actually see "server instances" on AI either... hmm..

Answer (score 0):

- If it was a standard app service plan those two functions would be sharing the SAME underlying compute (pool). With consumption however it's my understanding that because they are separate function apps they will get separate instances of compute for those apps behind the scenes because they are configured under a consumption plan.  Either way though I generally don't worry about the number of physical instances behind the scenes very often because I know either way Azure Functions will scale in a way to handle my workload. The Azure Functions team participates on stack overflow so maybe they can chime in to confirm the internals.
- The first thing I would highly suggest is to ensure each of your Function Apps are configured to use Application Insights. If the Function Apps are part of a related process I generally have them share a Application Insights instance so I can view all of their metrics together. Application Insights will provide you with everything you need in regards to the performance, exceptions, number of instances, and pretty much every other major characteristic of how your functions are operating (and you can add custom entries to fill any application specific gaps). You can set this up via the portal or ensure both function apps have the same Application Insights Key in their configuration. More instructions in usage\configuration can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring

Comment: yep, both use application insights, and this whole thread was raised as we are having issues with the consumption plan not scaling fast enough.. we need to monitor connections, and threads, and functions executions, and also i would like to keep an eye on instances too.. fingers crossed someone in the team replies soon.

Comment: Looks like an azure functions team member confirmed they share the same VM instances (I was wrong) but separate processes.  You mention you aren’t scaling fast enough. If these are http triggers they made some significant improvements to the scaling logic back in March that they were rolling out over time. You could howe ver get the new scaling logic immediately if you adding  WEBSITE_HTTPSCALEV2_ENABLED to 1 in your appsettings. More details at https://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/azure-functions-significant-improvements-in-http-trigger-scaling/ .  Think this still applies.

Comment: nice tip josh, thanks... we are using event hub triggers, but i shall commit that one to the memory bank :)